# Cannot generate app-group provisioning profile or get one that matches

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile, signing

I have an iOS app with an app group to receive inbound images from other apps.  I simply cannot get it to sign.  I have gone through signing a bunch so the process is very familiar but I can't even get the group identifier to show up under provisioning in the developer center.  Can someone help?  Here is the scenario ->

1. I cannot create a provisioning profile for my app group group.com.xxxxxx.bookapp.
2. I have made a new app group identifier group.com.xxxxxx.bookapp.
3. I have added it to my app identifier in com.xxxxxx.bookapp under capabilities in the dev center, and selected group.com.xxxxxx.bookapp and it looks correct.
4. I have regenerated all my provisioning profiles.
5. The app will build fine until it gets to the share extension target and it says Provisioning profile "Provisioning Profile Name" has app ID "com.xxxxxx.bookapp", which does not match the bundle ID "com.xxxxxx.bookapp.shareextension".
6. I cannot generate a provisioning profile for "com.xxxxxx.bookapp.shareextension" because it does not show up in the lists of available id's in the developer portal when I try to create a new profile.
7. I cannot use wildcard because I have push notifications and the share extension will not allow it anyways

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so, it turns out you have to create a whole new app id that goes with your app group, add the same app group to it as your main target, then create a provisioning profile for it like it is its own app.  Now I am able to publish like its two completely different apps, which is kinda is, just a bit convoluted and the docs don't really mention this.